# Angular 7 : mat-select cannot set default option without ngModel in a ReactiveForm

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Under my **Angular 7**  app; i'm using some reactive form.

my reative form is initilaized like this:

```
private initFormConfig() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      modeTransfert: [''],
      modeChiffrement: [''],
    });
  }
```

my form contains some inputs and some **mat-select** :

```
<div class="form-inline form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 justify-content-start">URL Cible</label>
          <input  id="urlCible"
                  type="text"
                  maxlength="200"
                  ngDefaultControl
                  formControlName="urlCible"
                  class="col-md-6 form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-inline form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 justify-content-start">Mode de transfert</label>
          <mat-form-field class="col-md-3" color="warn">
            <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner le mode de transfert"
                        id="modesTransfert"
                        [(value)]="selectedModeTransfert"
                        ngDefaultControl
                        formControlName="modeTransfert">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let modeTr of modeTransfertData"
                          [value]="modeTr.value">
                {{modeTr.viewValue}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to Set the initial default value for the select input : but i'm  struggling from two things :

- The fact that's **it's depecated in Angular 7 to use ngModel with a ngFormControl (reactive form)**
- the fact that patching its value like this :

  this.addPefForm.patchValue({'modeTransfert': this.modeTransfertData[0].value});

Cannot be done initially in the **onInit** or the **AfterViewChecked** hooks , because this results on this error :

```
ParametragePefAdministrationFormComponent.html:107 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-selected: false'. Current value: 'mat-selected: true'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:20342)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20330)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:20432)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:23305)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:23292)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:23896)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:23850)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ParametragePefAdministrationFormComponent.html:107)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23839)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:23193)
```

- also i ve tried to bind it with this : `[(value)]="selectedModeTransfert"`

all that didn't work .

**suggestions ??**

Answer (score 1):

When you need a default value for mat-select you need to specify it when you initiate the reactive form eg.

```
  states = [
    {name: 'Arizona', abbrev: 'AZ'},
    {name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA'},
    {name: 'Colorado', abbrev: 'CO'},
    {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Pennsylvania', abbrev: 'PA'},
  ];

  form = new FormGroup({
    state: new FormControl(this.states[3].abbrev),
  });

<mat-select formControlName="state">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.abbrev">
        {{state.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Now when your *ngFor the value will match the value provided in the FormControl.

This is also how you would show data retrieved from an API to auto fill the fields with the collected data.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: unfortenately i'm using the form builder syntax , i ve updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: Is there any reason you can't place a value where you have the empty strings in the formBuilder?

Comment: i ve tried it :       modeTransfert: [this.myData[0].value],

Comment: has the data for this.myData been populated before you are trying to call it inside your initFormConfig() function?

Comment: yes the data is already been loaded (it a local data exported from another file .

Comment: This: `modeTransfert: [this.myData[0].value]` should work (assuming that data is populated and it is the correct property). What is the error you are getting when you try that? (And consider updating your question to show the full syntax with this set.)

Comment: @DeborahK no error the mat select is initialized without a pre-selected option (default)

Comment: In your `initFormConfig`, if you `console.log()` out the value before creating the form, does it display the desired default option? If that works, then you may need to create a small stackblitz to demonstrate your issue?